# Tensorflow learns poorly if the output data form is tf.tensor2d(outputArr, [100,2]);

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

The neural network learns poorly if the output data form is tf.tensor2d(outputArr, [100,2]);
but when tf.tensor2d(inputArr, [100, 1]); then everything is fine, or tf.tensor2d(inputArr, [1, 1]);

I need to predict two multipliers, but when there are 2 output elements, the Loss does not go below 0.035. I copied all the code here. For example, when I predict 1 element, for example the result of division, then everything is fine.

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs')

const stateTf = reactive({
    result: 0,

});


let model = null
function initTf(){
    model = tf.sequential();
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [1], units: 2, activation: 'linear', useBias: true }));
    
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [2], units: 2, activation: 'linear', useBias: true }));
    model.compile({loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError, optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.01)});

    enterFrame()
}


async function doTraining(model, inputArr, outputArr, epochs = 1, batchSize=32) {

    let inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputArr, [100, 1]);
    let outputTensor = tf.tensor2d(outputArr, [100,2]);

    await model.fit(inputTensor, outputTensor, {
        batchSize,
        epochs: epochs, shuffle: true, callbacks: {
            onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
                console.log("epoch:"
                    + epoch
                    + " result:"
                    + JSON.stringify(logs));

            }
        }
    });
}

let requestId
let inputArr = []
let outputArr
let randomNumber
let randomNumber2
let maximum



function enterFrame()
{
    requestId = undefined;
    inputArr = []
    outputArr = []
    randomNumber = 0
    randomNumber2 = 0
    maximum = 100
    for(let i=0; i<100; i++){
        randomNumber = getRandomInt(1, maximum);
        randomNumber2 = getRandomInt(1, randomNumber);
        inputArr.push((randomNumber)/maximum)
        outputArr.push([(randomNumber/randomNumber2)/maximum, randomNumber2/maximum])
    }

    doTraining(model, inputArr, outputArr, 100).then(() => {
        const inputValue = [12/maximum];
        const prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor2d(inputValue,[1,1]));
        console.log(inputArr, outputArr)
        console.log("prediction:", prediction.arraySync()[0][0]*maximum);
        console.log("prediction:", prediction.arraySync()[0][1]*maximum);

        requestId = requestAnimationFrame(enterFrame);
    });



}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: The problem was that there were multiple answers, for example, to get the number 12, you could multiply 2 * 6 or 4 * 3. By changing it to the addition of two identical numbers, for example 5+5 = 10, everything started working well.